# Django passing form_valid inline formset context to get_context_data()

Tags: django, formset, inline-formset

I have a form with multiple nested inline formsets.  I am validating the inline formsets in form_valid, which errors are added to forms with errors.

Once the form_invalid fires, it returns->

```
return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form,
                                  note=note,
                                  enrollment=enrollment,
                                  mealCount=mealCount))
```

where note, enrollment, and mealCount are all inline formsets.

get_context_data, overrides any context saved in the form_valid method.

how can the context from form_valid be passed through to the get_context_data, so that the formsets can be instantiated with the correct context if available, or blank instances if no context was created in form_valid?

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(RoomCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    #post data was passed in form valid!
    if self.request.POST:
        context['enrollment'] = kwargs['enrollment']
        context['note'] = kwargs['note']
        context['mealCount'] = kwargs['mealCount']
    return context
```

Above, kwargs['*formsetname*'] gives 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_state'.  There is no instance of the inlineformset although an object exists.

at the time of the error this is the object in the stack:

<django.forms.formsets.RoomEnrollmentFormFormSet object at 0x00000203C0991B80>

Answer (score 0):

for anyone stumbling across this:

The fix was to capture errors and add them to the get context on create/update etc.  By doing this I was able to avoid having to create a CBV for each of the inline formsets. Capturing the errors set in the parent Form Valid and adding them to the unsaved instance of the inline formset with the following code:

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(*CBVNAME*, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    enrollmentErrors = kwargs['enrollment'].errors
    noteErrors = kwargs['note'].errors
    mcErrors = kwargs['mealCount'].errors
    if self.request.POST:
        context['enrollment'] = enrollmentFormSet(self.request.POST, instance = self.get_object())
        context['note'] = roomNoteFormSet(self.request.POST, instance = self.get_object())
        context['mealCount'] =roomUniqueMealCountFormSet(self.request.POST, instance = self.get_object())
        if enrollmentErrors:
            for num, form in enumerate(context['enrollment'].forms):
                for key in enrollmentErrors[num]:
                    field= None
                    if(key != '__all__'):
                        field = key
                    msg = enrollmentErrors[num][key].as_text()
                    form.add_error(field, msg)

        if noteErrors:
            for num, form in enumerate(context['note'].forms):
                for key in noteErrors[num]:
                    field= None
                    if(key != '__all__'):
                        field = key
                    msg = noteErrors[num][key].as_text()
                    form.add_error(field, msg)
        if mcErrors:
            for num, form in enumerate(context['mealCount'].forms):
                for key in mcErrors[num]:
                    field= None
                    if(key != '__all__'):
                        field = key
                    msg = mcErrors[num][key].as_text()
                    form.add_error(field, msg)
    else:
        context['enrollment'] = enrollmentFormSet(instance = self.get_object())
        context['note'] = roomNoteFormSet(instance = self.get_object())
        context['mealCount'] = roomUniqueMealCountFormSet(instance=self.get_object()) 

    return context
```