# How do I get FormSet to validate in my view?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am doing something a bit unusual with FormSets.  I am attempting to use a queryset as the input to my formset.  This seems to be working at this point just fine.  What isn't working is the form validation.  Thanks in advance for any thoughts.  I can't create this relationship via a traditional foreign key for reasons I won't bother people with.

My Models.py

```
class Team(models.Model):
    
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=264,null=False,blank=False)

class Player(models.Model):
    
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=264,null=False,blank=False)
    team_pk = models.integerfield(Team,null=True)
```

My views.py

```
class CreateTeamView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    model = Team
    form_class = CreateTeamForm
    template_name = 'create_team.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(CreateTeamView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    dropdown = self.request.GET.get("dropdown", None)
    queryset = Player.objects.filter(company_pk=dropdown)
    player_form = PlayerFormSet(queryset=queryset,dropdown=dropdown)
    context['player_form'] = player_form
    context['dropdown'] = dropdown
    return context

def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(CreateTeamView,self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
    kwargs['dropdown'] = self.request.GET.get("dropdown")
    return kwargs

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    dropdown=self.request.GET.get("dropdown")

    self.object = self.get_object()
    context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)

    self.object = None
    context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    form_kwargs = self.get_form_kwargs()
    player_form = PlayerFormSet(dropdown=dropdown)
    return self.render_to_response(
        self.get_context_data(form=form,
                              player_form=player_form,
                              context=context,
                              ))

def form_valid(self, form, player_form):
    self.object = form.save()
    player_form.instance = self.object
    player_form.save()

def form_invalid(self, form, player_form):

    return self.render_to_response(
        self.get_context_data(form=form,
                              player_form=player_form,
                              ))

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = None
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    dropdown=self.request.GET.get("dropdown")
    player_form = PlayerFormSet(dropdown,self.request.POST)
    if (form.is_valid() and player_form.is_valid()):
        return self.form_valid(form, player_form)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form, player_form)
```

My forms.py

```
class CreateTeamForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = Team

        fields=['team_name',]

PlayerFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Team, Player, extra=0, fields=['player_name',])

class PlayerFormSet(PlayerFormSet,BaseInlineFormSet):
    def __init__(self, dropdown, *args, **kwargs,): 
        super(PlayerFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.queryset = Player.objects.filter(teamp_pk=dropdown)
```

My template...

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="forms">

{% csrf_token %}

    {{ player_form.management_form }}

    {{ player_form.non_form_errors }}

    {% for hidden in player_form.management_form %}
        {{ hidden }}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for form in player_form.forms %}

      {{ form.id }}

      <div class="inline {{ player_form.prefix }}">
        <div class="leftwidth22">
          <div class="width52">
            <h2 class="floatright23">Player Name - </h2>
          </div>
        </div>
          <div class="rightwidth53">
            <h2 class="width70">
              {{ form.player_name }}
            </h2>
          </div>

        {% if player_form.non_form_errors %}

          <h3 class="spacer12">
            {{ player_form.non_form_errors }}
          </h3>

        {% endif %}

        {% if form.player_name.errors %}

          <h3 class="spacer12">
            {{ form.player_name.errors }}
          </h3>

        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}

</form>
```

The good news is that this is all working in that it is now passing the formset data that I was after to the form.  What I'm stuck on now is the form set processing.  Because the form data is all new...I realize that I need to do some kind of loop through the form_valid part of the code but I can't quite make it out....

I've tried...

```
data = self.get_context_data()
formset = data['player_form']
if formset.is_valid():
    self.object = form.save()
    formset.instance = self.object
    formset.save()
```

But I literally get zero error messages.  The form will submit if I don't change anything.  But that defeats the purpose.  I need to be able to change the data in the form and then submit it.

Update....I've gotten a bit further...using the code below in my post function...in my class based view....

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = None
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    dropdown=self.request.GET.get("dropdown")
    team_form = TeamFormSet(dropdown,self.request.POST)
    if (form.is_valid() and team_form.is_valid()):
        players = team_form.save(commit=False)
        for player in players:
            player = form.save(commit=False)
            player.save()
        return self.form_valid(form, team_form)
```

This kind of works.  Sometimes.  If I update the form via the view and delete an entry...the save will not work saying that save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object.  I've looked most of today at atomic saves and varying degrees of formset saves and nothing is working.  Thanks in advance for any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong.

Update...

```
        team_form = TeamForm(request.POST)
        player_form = PlayerForm(self.request.POST)
        if player_form.is_valid():
            for form in team_form:
                print("works")
            player_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Team:main_menu'))
        else:
            for form in team_form:
                if form.is_valid():
                    form.save(commit=False)
                    print("nope")
                else:
                    print(form.errors)
                # return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Team:team_menu'))
                return self.form_invalid(form, playerform)
```

I can loop through my formset now, and determine where the error is, but when I do it comes back with object has no attribute 'object'.

Here's the traceback data...

Exception Type: TypeError at /Company/update_saved_new_company/
Exception Value: form_invalid() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Traceback data for object has no attribute 'object'

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\steve\Envs\Final5Production\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\steve\Envs\Final5Production\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\steve\Envs\Final5Production\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Project\Project\mixins.py", line 46, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\steve\Envs\Final5Production\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py", line 52, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\steve\Envs\Final5Production\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Company\views.py", line 9283, in post
    return super(UpdateSavedNewCompanyView, self).form_invalid(company_contact_form)
  File "C:\Users\steve\Envs\Final5Production\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 61, in form_invalid
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
  File "C:\Company\views.py", line 9036, in get_context_data
    context = super(UpdateSavedNewCompanyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\steve\Envs\Final5Production\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 67, in get_context_data
    return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\steve\Envs\Final5Production\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py", line 94, in get_context_data
    if self.object:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /Company/update_saved_new_company/
Exception Value: 'UpdateSavedNewCompanyView' object has no attribute 'object'
```

Comment: Please show full traceback.

Comment: Why do you iteration if formset is not valid, why not `player_form.errors`?

Comment: If formset is not valid, I am trying to get it to show the form validation.  Currently it will not.

Comment: Ok, but `player_form.errors` or `if team_form.is_valid() else team_form.errors`. Doesn't it show errors?

Comment: I keep winding up in a vicious cycle.  When the error is tripped I print it out and can see it in my console.  On the screen it says that form_invalid() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given.  I can't figure out how to get past that.

Comment: In any case show your full traceback. Then we can see why.

Comment: I've never done one before.  What is best approach?

Comment: What error print Django, [exception details](https://avilpage.com/2015/05/whats-so-good-about-django-traceback.html).

Comment: I updated it...I looked through the lines for the error for the 2 positional arguments....it basically just said....Exception Type: TypeError at /Company/update_saved_new_company/
Exception Value: form_invalid() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: As errors says you provide 2 arguments. You have to provide only one form > `return super(CreateTeamView, self).form_invalid(form)`. And you have to break iteration before return something.

Comment: Thank you what do you mean by break iteration before return something?

Comment: I get past that error and it now says...object has no attribute 'object'.

Comment: Updated issue with Traceback.

Comment: And I also found this issue which appears very closely related....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62918614/django-passing-form-valid-inline-formset-context-to-get-context-data

Comment: Why do you set self.object to None in post?

Comment: Remove this line `self.object = None` from `post` and `get` methods. UpdateView must have an object.

Comment: I removed them and still getting no object error.

Comment: Please update your question with the current view code.

Comment: I will make a new question about object error with current code.  Hang on a few.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I created this new issue with a different question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67028871/how-do-i-solve-model-object-has-no-attribute-object-for-updateview-for-forms