# How do I properly pass KWARG keyword to get_context_data?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am narrowing down an issue with my formset handling and I feel like this solution could be my answer.  [Django passing form_valid inline formset context to get_context_data()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62918614/django-passing-form-valid-inline-formset-context-to-get-context-data)

However, when I try it, I am getting an error trying to add the

```
  enrollmentErrors = kwargs['enrollment'].errors
```

It says...

KeyError: 'enrollment'

I'm not new to Django...but formsets have me thoroughly challenged.  Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Comment: Could you show more of your code ?  Are you sure you are supposed to have an 'enrollment' key at this point in your code ?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  No I'm not sure.  I have laid out my code here in this issue.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66960993/how-do-i-get-formset-to-validate-in-my-view  I am now at a point where I can loop through individual forms, but when I hit a problematic form, that's where I am getting the error.  I was trying to solve for it using this suggestion, but can't quite make it out.