# How do I solve 'Model' object has no attribute 'object' for UpdateView for formset handling?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am currently trying to get past numerous problems I've encountered with formset handling.  Here is my latest code...In other issues it would seem that there might be an issue with formset and form_invalid().  I am trying to simply edit formset data that I have saved from a CreateView.  It seems as if the data is presenting fine in the view after I save it from CreateView, but then I am not able to use this data or save it without changing anything.  This issue seems eerily similar and I tried to use it to a degree but I couldn't get it to work either...[Django passing form_valid inline formset context to get_context_data()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62918614/django-passing-form-valid-inline-formset-context-to-get-context-data)

My View....

```
class UpdateTeamView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    model = Team
    form_class = UpdateTeamForm
    template_name = 'update_team.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(UpdateTeamView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if self.request.POST:
        context['player_form'] = PlayerFormSet(self.request.POST)
    else:
        context['player_form'] = PlayerFormSet(instance=self.object)
    return context

def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(UpdateTeamView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
    return kwargs

def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    return get_object_or_404(Team, id=self.request.GET.get("dropdown"))

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    dropdown=self.request.GET.get("dropdown")
    if dropdown is not None:
        if Team.objects.all().distinct():
            self.object = self.get_object()
            context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
            return self.render_to_response(context)
        else:
            raise Http404
    else:
        messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, 'Team is required.')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Company:update_team_by_name'))

def form_valid(self, form):
    instance = form.save()
    return super(UpdateTeamView, self).form_valid(form)

def form_invalid(self, form):    
     return self.render_to_response(
        self.get_context_data(form=form,
                              ))

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    if "cancel" in request.POST:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Company:company_main_menu'))
    else:
        team_form = TeamForm(self.request.POST)
        player_form = UpdateSavedNewCompanyContactFormSet(self.request.POST)
        if player_form.is_valid():
            print("works")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Team:main_menu'))
        else:
            player_form = UpdateSavedNewCompanyContactFormSet()
            print("not working")
            print(player_form.errors)
            return super(UpdateTeamView, self).form_invalid(player_form)
```

Comment: I'm on to something.  Post is not needed here.  It is causing more problems than good.  I still can't get my data to validate but am now looking to update the logic in form_valid().

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error here was my solution....

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(UpdateTeamView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if self.request.POST:
        context['player_form'] = PlayerFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
    else:
        context['player_form'] = PlayerFormSet(instance=self.object)
    return context

def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(UpdateTeamView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
    return kwargs

def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    return get_object_or_404(UpdateTeamView, id=self.request.GET.get("dropdown"))

def form_valid(self, form):

    data = self.get_context_data()
    formset = data['company_contact_form']

    if formset.is_valid():
        self.object = form.save()
        formset.instance = self.object
    else:
        print('formset invalid:', formset.errors)

    instance = form.save()

def form_invalid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):        
    super().form_invalid()
```